# Hydrazine as a reduction agent

Tags: redox

When using hydrazine as a reduction agent to reduce graphene oxide, which is the product hydrazine oxidises to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm sorry for the wrong answer initially given; you might consider to unaccept this one.*

I'm not sure whether this has ever been examined in detail. It is likely that nobody bothered to collect the (volatile) reaction products of hydrazine.

According to a procedure provided by the group of **Rodney Ruoff** ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.carbon.2007.02.034)), the reduction was performed in an open flask equipped with a reflux condenser. An aqueous suspension GO was first sonicated (to support exfoliation) until it became clear, then hydrazine hydrate was added and the mixture refluxed at 100 °C for 24 hours. During this time, the reduction product precipitated as a black solid.

No remarks on what actually happened to the hydrazine were given in this article.

Comment: If hydrazine is acting as a reducing agent, then it should be oxidized during the reaction.

Comment: @jerepierre You're absolutely right. I was thinking in oxidative degradation of carboxylates, which has nothing to do with the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

The decomposition reaction of hydrazine ($\ce{N2H4}$) is as below:
$$\ce{N2H4 \rightarrow N2H2 + H2}$$

The forming $\ce{H2}$ will reduce the graphene oxide and hydrazine itself oxidises to $\ce{N2H2}$.

Comment: So, why not use H2 in the first place?

Comment: To avoid contaminating the graphene with metals I suspect.